# Вопрос по ооп

Tags: ооп, java

```
class ExampleClass {

    int a = 1;

    void exampleMethod() {
          new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                 System.out.print(a);
             }
         }.run();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new ExampleClass()).exampleMethod(); 
    }
}
```

Здесь всё ок, выводится 1.

А теперь добавим переменную с аналогичным именем в метод

```
class ExampleClass {

    int a = 1;

    void exampleMethod() {
          final int a = 2;
          new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                 System.out.print(a);
             }
         }.run();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new ExampleClass()).exampleMethod(); 
    }
}
```

Выводится, как понимаете, двойка.

Собственно вопрос. **Как во втором примере добраться до того a, которое a = 1**

Comment: @Fike, нет this.a будет искать в полях Runnable, поэтому 


   Main.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
                 System.out.print(this.a);
                                      ^
     symbol: variable a
   1 error

Comment: @danpetruk, да, я по диагонали прочитал. Костыль через временную переменную (`int b = this.a`) не взлетит?

Comment: @Fike, нет)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш экземпляр Runnable является вложенным классом, а это значит, что у него есть ссылка на класс, в который он вложен. Вспоминаем как получить эту ссылку и получаем:

```
class ExampleClass {

int a = 1;

void exampleMethod() {
      final int a = 2;
      new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
             System.out.print(ExampleClass.this.a);
         }
     }.run();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    (new ExampleClass()).exampleMethod(); 
}
}
```